# enable the button to be clicked only to once exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a dialog to get the user input, but I found the user may click double click the button and added the content twice, the cause is the dialog fadeout too slow or the user clicked twice on the mouse.. I don't want to adjust the fadeout speed, instead, how to enable the button only can be clicked once?

Comment: we need to see some of your code before we can give a definitive answer, but generally you will want to do that in the click event.  You might even unbind it with off (I think it was?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the button once it was clicked to prevent any further clicks:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 16):

jQuery provides the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to register a one-shot handler that will only run once.

You can write:

```
$("#yourButton").one("click", function() {
    // Add content...
});
```

Comment: oh snap! when was that added?  That's a nice feature!

Comment: @Joseph, the first form (similar to `bind()`) was introduced way back in jQuery 1.1. The other two forms (similar to `on()`) were introduced in version 1.7, like `on()` itself.

Comment: I had no idea that was in there all this time.  If only I could vote twice.  This is the most technically correct answer... and something I hadn't seen before.  Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion.  If you are destroying the dialog on exit, just unbind the click event

```
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
    // process code
    $(this).off('click');
});
```

You can read about off [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wwuj7/show).  First will not allow other clicks but the second will.

[source](http://jsfiddle.net/wwuj7/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T7k6lz5uoCjzqFGfYzgd?p=preview) that shows how you can do this. Pretty much all you need to do is add the following line in your button:

```
onClick="this.disabled = true;"
```

So that your button HTML will look something like this:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="this.disabled = true;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: inline javascript is generally discouraged as a bad practice.

Comment: Joseph, I completely agree. While this question was tagged with jQuery there were no code examples and so I put forward an answer that solved the problem. If he had provided code that used `$(el).on(...)` then I would have suggested using `$(this).off(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $('.myButton').click(function(){ 

        $(this).attr('disabled',true);

             ....
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with css

```
$("#yourButton").one("click", function() {
     $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
})
```